# Arbitrary running @Configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot

By "arbitrary" I refer to the ability to do an action whenever it's wanted. So, with that, what is intended here is to run @Configuration classes only when it's explicitly called or when it's strictly needed (instead of running automatically as soon spring context is up, which is the default behavior).

Describing a bit of my scenario: the @Configuration class is a database configuration and connection class. Although I don't want it to be created automatically, as soon the application starts (default spring behavior). Instead, I'm looking for a way to programmaticaly build and connect to it, strictly when I call for it to do so.

So the question would be: ***How to prevent @Configuration classes from automatically running and after that, how should it be "re-enabled" again to be able to run?***

**Please note that NONE of that below worked out as expected:**

Tried using @Conditional, and at first it seemed to be the perfect fit, although @Conditional expressions (or based on some kind of logic or property like @ConditionalOnProperty) runs once after application context is built, which means that the value being passed to the annotation could even change, although that class wouldn't react to the @Conditional expression changes (which would be perfect, like, telling spring "run that configuration class after property name X is set")

Something like that:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "X", havingValue = "true")
public class DatabaseTest {
// bean is not created, no value for property X
```

then, after setting a value to X with

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("X", "anyValue"));
```

Although it works per as described above, the class do not react to the property changes.

Another attempt was to use @DependsOn and @Order, but still, those beans annotated with it automatically runs as soon the depending beans are created.

Also tried using

```
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters  = {@ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {ConfigurationClass2.class, ConfigurationClass1.class})})
```

and it do prevent @Configuration classes from running, but I have no idea how to switch it back working.

Comment: This pretty much sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I understand you correctly, you want that the connection is created when you set some property at runtime, and is later destroyed when the property is reset? This has consequences. I suspect that you use this bean somewhere (through DI), and those beans can only (!) be created when the conditional bean is present, and must be destroyed when the conditional bean is destroyed. This is not how a DI container normally operates. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Not a XY problem because as described, those configuration classes are running automatically, which causes issues setting the correct database configurations. Responding to your question, I want this because I have multiple h2 databases under a specific path. Based on a selection it's done once the application starts, it's needed to build and connect to the selected database, instead of automatically connecting to one of them

Comment: Why not create connections to all of them, and use the connection needed in the specific use cases?

Comment: Cause some of it might not exist (based on the selection options), so a custom database is created based on pre-configuration, once that configuration is done, then I can safely run the database connection algorithm based on the new custom configuration

Comment: all that algorithm is done and working, I just need to make my @Configuration class wait till the custom configuration is set

Comment: responding to your question after edit: that's exactly my goal, I want to use the connection needed in the specific use cases, but the use cases are set before the database creation and connection, that's why I need to hold the @Configuration class till the use cases are set

Comment: I would suggest you to pay attention to @Turing85 advice: it looks like you have found a convenient way to configure data source via configurations and now looking for a way to make configurations dynamic - configurations are not designed for such scenarios, instead you need to learn about proxies and/or prototype scope. Implementations of org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDataSource might help you as well.

Comment: I don't see any way proxies and prototype scope would help at all. I'm not looking to conditionally run a specific @Bean method but the entire class. Although AbstractDataSource seems very interesting approach and I'll be definitely giving it a shot. Thanks for suggesting